# Where to accept invitations in Azure for static web apps?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I'm building a static website in Azure and want to use this function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization

When I try to invite a user, it explains that an administrator as to accept this invitation, but where does he have to do this? I cannot see an option for this in portal.azure.com

it also seems not to be possible to "preload" the roleassignments to the users. because on the "acccessmanagement" site for this website in portal.azure.com it grants the access to the complete resource in portal.azure.com, but I just want the user to use the website.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
kind regards

Comment: Hi @user8023956, Please share the exact message where "administrator has to accept this invitation"

Comment: Genehmigung erforderlich
 
Azure Static Web Apps
identity.azurestaticapps.net
Für diese App ist die Genehmigung Ihres Administrators für Folgendes erforderlich:

Grundlegendes Profil von Benutzern anzeigen

Zugriff auf Daten beibehalten, für die Sie Zugriff erteilt haben

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the invitation instructions in that [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization#invitations), you need to copy the link from the "Invite" link box and actually send it to the person.

1. Navigate to a Static Web Apps resource in the Azure portal.
2. Under Settings, click on Role Management.
3. Click on the Invite button.
4. Select an Authorization provider from the list of options.
5. Add either the username or email address of the recipient in the Invitee details box. For GitHub and Twitter, you enter the username. For all others, enter the recipient's email address.
6. Select the domain of your static site from the Domain drop-down.
7. The domain you select is the domain that appears in the invitation. If you have a custom domain associated with your site, you probably want to choose the custom domain.
8. Add a comma-separated list of role names in the Role box.
9. Enter the maximum number of hours you want the invitation to remain valid.
   The maximum possible limit is 168 hours, which is 7 days.
10. Click the Generate button.
11. **Copy the link from the Invite link box.**
12. **Email the invitation link to the person you're granting access to your app.**

Comment: hi,
we did analyze this case and found out that there is an app 'azure static web app' which tries to access the tenant-data. this is what has to be granted and in an enterprise environment not everyone is able to do this. Next step is to make an it-security assesment to check this app and grant it. after that i think the invitations should work. but i am still not able to preset a role for everyone in my organization. ‍♂️

Comment: Is this a "one time" action or do we need to do it for every new user?

Comment: @Woozar invitation is only when you want to assign a custom role, for registering a new user you may be able to use MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library)